# OpenCV - DISOptical Flow Presets

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I noticed that in the OpenCV_Contrib modules, there is a DISOpticalFlow algorithm which has 3 presets: Medium, Fast and UltraFast.

Does anyone know what the tradeoff between speed and accuracy is between these? I understand that the parameters are set [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/optflow/src/dis_flow.cpp), but is there any analysis on how these effect speed and accuracy?

Thanks.